# how do you execute a sql command on a button click and then have it populate a dataset?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net

Ok I have a SQL query that I need to run on a button click and then output to a dataset.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        var line = txtLine.Text;
        var serial = txtSerial.Text;
        var station = txtStation.Text;
    }

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var line = txtLine.Text;
        var serial = txtSerial.Text;
        var station = txtStation.Text;

        if (txtLine.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Line");
        }
        else if (txtSerial.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Serial");
        }
        else if (txtStation.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Station");
        }
        else
        {
            //SQL command goes here.
        }
    }
}
```

I have the SQL command I just need to know how to execute it as a non store procedure and output the data to the dataGridView1 object.

Comment: You're asking a question in 10 years old topic, since that there are thousands of articles, blog posts and Stackoverflow answers.

Comment: You will want to setup a connection and command object to excute your ExcuteNonquery sql type. Look up Ado.net excuting non query.

Comment: You realise that about 50% of the code you've posted does nothing?

Comment: try google-ing it then READ.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough informations to show you more than pseudo code. However, use the `using`  statement to ensure that everything implementing `IDisposable` gets disposed properly and the connection   gets closed (even on error).

Use sql-parameters to avoid sql injection and conversion/localization issues.

```
string sql = "SELECT Columns FROM dbo.TableName WHERE Column=@ParamName";
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Connection String Here"))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamName", "Param Value");
    // other parameters
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(table);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;             
}
```